# reactjs onChange firing callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a password confirmation checker in `reactJS`. I am currently testing out firing the callbacks within the component. When I test this view, I dont see my `onChange` firing off any callbacks. I am pretty new to `reactjs` so I'm not sure why nothing is happening.

```
import React from 'react';

class SignUp extends React.Component {

    confirmPassword(event) {
        console.log("confirmPassword");
        console.log(event);
    }

    setInitialPassword(event) {
        console.log("setInitialPassword");
        console.log(event);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form method="post" action="/signup">
                    <ul>
                        <li><input id="firstName" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" type="text" required="required" /></li>
                        <li><input id="lastName" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" type="text" required="required" /></li>
                        <li><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required="required" /></li>
                        <li><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ this.setInitialPassword }/></li>
                        <li><input id="confirmPassword" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ this.confirmPassword } /></li>
                        <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirm-message"></span>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?  It seems to work correctly in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5gtfbcv/1/

Comment: Its works with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15118/. By the way you should write `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: If you use `React.createClass` instead of the ES6 class syntax, you get autobinding and this will Just Work™.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` when you set your handlers.

```
<li><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ this.setInitialPassword.bind(this) }/></li>
<li><input id="confirmPassword" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ this.confirmPassword.bind(this) } /></li>
```

or using ES6 big arrow functions:

```
<li><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ e => this.setInitialPassword(e) }/></li>
<li><input id="confirmPassword" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" required="required" onChange={ e => this.confirmPassword(e) } /></li>
```